# How to keep icons from becoming glossy with Xcode 5 and iOS7?

Tags: ios, xcode, icons, ios7, xcode5

After switching to Xcode 5 and using asset bundles for my app icons, installing the app on an iOS6 device results in an icon with Apple's stock gloss overlaid, even though I have specified in my plist that the icon already includes gloss.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This option is now moved to the asset bundle:

[image: New place]

Look at the option on the right: "iOS icon is pre-rendered". Took me some time to figure this one out.